# How do I block emails from going out to certain MX servers in postfix?

Tags: postfix

We're using a simple postfix configuration to relay emails through the actual mail server: all the applications are pointed to our relay server, and that relay server has some transport_maps config that block delivery to some domains. It sends everything else through the actual mail server.
I'm trying to find a way to block certain MX servers on this intermediate postfix relay server.

Note that we are not *accepting* any external emails. This relay server is only used by our own applications. The problem is that users are abusing the applications and sending emails to fake email addresses. For example, if someone makes the application send an email to bob@foo.com, I'd like to check what the mx record for foo.com is - if it's 1.2.3.4 (the abusers' mail server), I'd like to reject this email. For all other MX servers, I'd like to proceed as usual.

I think smtpd_recipient_restrictions might be able to do this (using check_recipient_mx_access) but I'm having trouble understanding how to configure this and not having much luck finding clear examples. Is this possible, and if so, could someone show a simple example?

Comment: Manually maintaining email blocklists is rarely a permanent solution to any problem. Are you certain you should be manually blocking some destinations, instead of just configuring allowed targets and blocking **all** other relaying?

Comment: Our apps allow customers to send emails to themselves with our data in them, and we have many customers throughout the world, so we can't just allow certain domains.